# remap emacs key

Tags: emacs, key

I would like to remap a key in emacs, for example `{` and i would it to trigger usual event.
Example, i remapped `alt` + `(` to get `{` and i would like, when i use a plugin like `autopair` to give me the associated `}`.
I tried this :

```
    (global-set-key [(alt \()] ( lambda () (interactive) (insert "{") ))
```

It inserts `{` correctly but does not trigger `autopair` hooks.

Is there a way to achieve it ?

Comment: It looks like autopair itself works by rebinding keys. So this isn't going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (not tested):

```
(define-key key-translation-map (kbd "M-(") (kbd "{"))
```